# Existence of a specific prime

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

Reading some background on the Brocard-Ramanujan equation I found a proof which says the following. For a fixed natural number $A$ which is not a square it is always possible to find a prime $p$ such that

1. $p>A$;
2. $x^2\equiv A \pmod{p}$ has no solution (that is, $A$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $p$).

However, the proof does not say anything about how it is possible. I do not find it so evident. Maybe I am missing some very basic fact.

Comment: Find a number $n$ that is not a quadratic residue modulo $A$. By Dirichlet's Theorem on primes in arithmetic progression (and the Chinese Remainder Theorem), there is a prime $p$ comgruent to $n$ modulo $A$ and to $1$ modulo $4$. By quadratic reciprocity, the Jacobi symbols $(A|p)$ and $(p|A)$ are equal. But....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is a non-square, let $B=q_1\dots q_l\,$ its non-square part, i.e.   write $A=BC$, where $C$ is a square and $B$ has no repeated prime factor. It is enough to find a prime $p>A$ such that $B$ is a non-square modulo $p$. Actually, we'll find one such that $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$.

- If $B$ is odd, using the *Legendre symbol*, we have by the law of quadratic reciprocity law:
  $$\biggl(\frac Bp\biggr)=\prod_{i=1}^l\Bigl(\frac{q_i}p\Bigr)=\prod_{i=1}^l\Bigl(\frac p{q_i}\Bigr)\bigl(-1\bigr)^{\tfrac{(p-1)(q_i-1)}4}=\prod_{i=1}^l\Bigl(\frac p{q_i}\Bigr)$$
  By the *Chinese remainder theorem*, we can find an $x$ which is not a square modulo $p_1$,  is modulo $p_i\ (i>1)$, and such that $x\equiv 1\bmod4$.

  Now by *Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions*, among the elements $x+4kB=x+ 4kq_1\dots q_l$, which are squares modulo each $q_i$, there are primes $p>A$. For such a $p$, we have $p\equiv 1\mod4$, so that $\biggl(\dfrac Bp\biggr)=-1$.
- If $B$ is even, write $B=2B'$. We slightly modify the previous argument: first choose an $x$ that additionally is congruent to $1\bmod 8$. Then consider a prime $p>A$ in the arithmetic progression:
  $$x+4kB=x+8kB'$$
  By the previous case, $B'$ is not a square modulo $p$, and since $\,p\equiv1\bmod8$, by the *Second supplementary law*:
  $$\biggl(\frac Bp\biggr)= \biggl(\frac 2p\biggr)\biggl(\frac{B'}p\biggr)=\bigl(-1\bigr)^{\tfrac{p^2-1}8}\cdot(-1)=-1 $$

Therefore in either case, $B$ is not a square modulo $p$.

Comment: I see your point that the we can take the square-free part. But how do you find such a prime for the remaining $B$? Sorry if it should be evident but I do not see how it is much more easier than the original problem.

Comment: My answer was published unwittingly before I had finished to type it. Please wait a moment.

Comment: Your proof is very nice. Here comes the acceptance and an upvote. Thanks! :)

Comment: I deleted the previous comment, because I do not want to flood. So, in the first step of writing the Legendre-symbol as a product, I do not think that you need the minus sign. Also in the quadratic reciprocity it should be $q_i\equiv 3$ and you need that $p$ is congruent to $q_i$ in such case to have the minus. Please check if I am saying the right things.

Comment: I'll do it as soon as I have some time. Anyway, I'd like to simplify the proof. Thanks to your comment, I've seen there's a problem with the minus sign, unless we suppose $p\equiv 3\mod 4$, but I'm not not sure we can suppose it (nor the other case).

Comment: For that period I unaccept the answer, it let others think about the problem. The vote still remains because your answer is very useful and probably the way to do the proof even if with some little modifications to work around the problematic situation.

Comment: @M. Szikszai: I've just modified (and simplified) the proof, which should be fully functional now.

Comment: You did a great job, thanks for your time! I hoped that the problem will turn out to be non-trivial, and it did.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment. Just a hint to make Bernard's idea work. Show that among the elements of forms $1+kB$ or $1+2kB$ there are infinitely many primes which are congruent to $3$ mod $4$, otherwise you reach some contradiction with existence of primes of some form. Just an idea, I have not made it through.

Comment: That was more or less my idea. I didn't have enough time to try to elaborate, but I keep thinking about it…